# How to print an arrays, that have the same elements which are not in order

Tags: arrays, c

I have int 2-5 arrays (user decision how much), each of which has its own elements. I need to compare them to print their names.

For example, I have 3 arrays, First contains: 3, 41, 315, 2. Second contains: 5, 31, 315. The Third one contains: 315, 41, 3, 2, 2, 41. How can I compare their elements, to print names of the arrays that have the same elements, like this: ("FIRST THIRD").
(They can be in or out of order, and they can repeat);**

I tried to play with indexes of arrays, if array1[0] == array2[0], then compare other elements, but it will take a while to write this all, and it will take a lot of space, maybe there is a cleaner fix for this?

```
    #define N 6
    int arr1[N] = { 3, 41, 315, 2 }, arr2[N] = { 5, 31, 315 }, arr3[N] = {315, 41, 3, 2, 2, 41};
    
    for (int h = 0; h <= N; h++)
if (arr1[j] == arr2[h])
        {
            // compare other elements of arrays one by one adding indexes of arrays 
        }
        }
```

I want it to output :

> First Third

Comment: what is arr1 amd arr2 and why are you using strdup on an array of ints?

Comment: `*_strdup(arr1)` seems very wrong. First non of your arrays are strings, secondly it typicall allocate memory which you throw away which leads to memory leaks. Why not plain `arr1[0]`?

Comment: Also a name like `arrascii1` seems misleading, since you have arrays of `int` numbers and not any ASCII encoded characters.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude arr1 arr2 arr3 arr4 arr5 is char string where I saved words, like arr1 "Hello" arr2 "World", etc. I converted those letters from arr1 into int arrascii1, from arr2 into int arrascii2, etc.
Now I want to compare those elements of int arr's, basicly to find words with same letters, to print them later.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to show us a [mre]. There's just too little context. And `*_strdup(...)` will still be wrong.

Comment: You are mixing up strdup with strlen, maybe.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I changed strdup as you ask to something more readable

Comment: I have deleted my answer, because I noticed that I misunderstood your question. I will adapt my answer and then undelete it.

Comment: What should the output be if the arrays `arr1` and `arr3` have exactly the same content? Should it be `First Third\nThird First\n` because both arrays contain all numbers of the other array, in both directions?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel , arr1 and arr3 have the same content, but in different order and different amount, program that I want should compare arr1 and arr2, arr1 and arr3, arr2 and arr3, so it could find arrays with the same elements no matter what order and what amount are they. Output should ne like: **Array1 have the same elements as Array3.**

Comment: @HiFox: So if `arr3` instead contains an extra `7` at the end, then your program should not print anything, because all comparisons fail, despite the fact that all of the elements in `arr1` exist in `arr3`? All elements in `arr3` must also exist in `arr1` for the comparison to succeed?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel , yes, there should be only the same elements (arr1= 3,3,2,5;arr 2 = 2,3,5,5;) for it to pass

Comment: The problem statement is lacking... It now seems that all of the elements of the smallest of a pair of arrays must be present at least once (in any sequence) in the larger of the pair... (as stated in the OP "FIRST THIRD"... Now, it seems any pair must be the same size, with elements possibly shuffled... Defining the objective clearly would save time for everyone.

Comment: @HiFox: I have now updated my answer.

Comment: If `arr1` or `arr2` have `N` elements (or less), then your loop will go out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Performance isn't great, but you can define a function `contained_in` that checks to see if everything in one array is in another.

```
int contained_in(int *arr1, size_t n1, int *arr2, size_t n2) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
        int contained = 0;
        for (size_t j = 0; j < n2 && !contained; j++) {
            if (arr1[i] == arr2[j]) {
                contained = 1;
            }
        }

        if (!contained) return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

If you check `contained_in(arrascii1, N, arrascii2, N)` *and* `contained_in(arrascii2, N, arrascii1, N)` then you'll know that both contain the same values.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of defining the arrays `arr1`, `arr2` and `arr3` as separate arrays, it would probably be easier to define an array of arrays, for example like this:

```
#define NUM_ARRAYS 3
#define N 6

int arrays[NUM_ARRAYS][N] = {
    {  3,  41, 315, 2 },
    {  5,  31, 315 },
    { 315, 41,   3, 2, 2, 41}
};
```

That way you can use the indexes of both dimensions in loops, which will make the coding easier:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define NUM_ARRAYS 3
#define N 6

//This function returns true if the right array contains all
//elements of the left array, and vice versa. Otherwise it returns false.
bool compare_arrays( int left[], int right[] )
{
    //check whether right array contains all elements in the
    //left array
    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j = 0; ; j++ )
        {
            if ( j == N )
                return false;

            if ( left[i] == right[j] )
                break;
        }
    }

    //check whether left array contains all elements in the
    //right array
    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j = 0; ; j++ )
        {
            if ( j == N )
                return false;

            if ( right[i] == left[j] )
                break;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

int main( void )
{
    const char *map[] = {
        "First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth", "Fifth",
        "Sixth", "Sevent", "Eighth", "Ninth", "Tenth"
    };

    int arrays[NUM_ARRAYS][N] = {
        {   3, 41, 315, 2 },
        {   5, 31, 315 },
        { 315, 41,   3, 2, 2, 41 }
    };

    for ( int i = 0; i < NUM_ARRAYS; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j = i + 1; j < NUM_ARRAYS; j++ )
        {
            if ( compare_arrays( arrays[i], arrays[j] ) )
                printf( "%s %s\n", map[i], map[j] );
        }
    }
}
```

However, this program has no output. That is because the array `arr1` also contains the value `0` in its last two elements, which do not exist in `arr3`. Therefore, the comparison of `arr1` and `arr3` fails.

The reason why the value of the last two elements is `0` is because if at least one element of the array is initialized, then all elements that are not explicitly initialized are implicitly initialized to `0`.

For the reasons stated above, it would be appropriate to have an additional variable for every array, which specifies the number of valid elements in the array. Instead of using separate variables, it would probably be better to group them with the array in a `struct`:

```
struct array_with_length
{
    int length;
    int array[N];
};
```

That way, you can limit the loops to the number of valid elements:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define NUM_ARRAYS 3
#define N 6

struct array_with_length
{
    int length;
    int array[N];
};

//This function returns true if the right array contains all
//elements of the left array, and vice versa. Otherwise it returns false.
bool compare_arrays(
    const struct array_with_length *left,
    const struct array_with_length *right
)
{
    //check whether right array contains all elements in the
    //left array
    for ( int i = 0; i < left->length; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j = 0; ; j++ )
        {
            if ( j == right->length )
                return false;

            if ( left->array[i] == right->array[j] )
                break;
        }
    }

    //check whether left array contains all elements in the
    //right array
    for ( int i = 0; i < right->length; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j = 0; ; j++ )
        {
            if ( j == left->length )
                return false;

            if ( right->array[i] == left->array[j] )
                break;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

int main( void )
{
    const char *map[] = {
        "First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth", "Fifth",
        "Sixth", "Sevent", "Eighth", "Ninth", "Tenth"
    };

    struct array_with_length arrays[NUM_ARRAYS] = {
        {
            4, //number of elements in array
            {   3, 41, 315, 2 }, //array content
        },

        {
            3, //number of elements in array
            {   5, 31, 315 }, //array content
        },

        {
            6, //number of elements in array
            { 315, 41, 3, 2, 2, 41 } //array content
        }
    };

    for ( int i = 0; i < NUM_ARRAYS; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j = i + 1; j < NUM_ARRAYS; j++ )
        {
            if ( compare_arrays( &arrays[i], &arrays[j] ) )
                printf( "%s %s\n", map[i], map[j] );
        }
    }
}
```

This program has the following output:

```
First Third
```

This is the output that you said that you wanted.

Comment: Always seeking to reduce code, a quick test (before the call, or in the compare function) could, if needed 'swap' the pair being compared. All the elements of a 'larger' array will never fit into a 'smaller' one.

Comment: @Fe2O3: Yes, I thought of doing that and in code that I write for myself or for experienced programmers, I would normally do that. However, I didn't want the code to be too hard to understand for OP.